# Is there a way to hide the same values in MultiIndex level 1?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, latex, multi-index

I have the following dataframe (named `test`) in pandas:

```
 Group 1 Group 2  Species                     Adj. P-value
0   a      b      Parabacteroides goldsteinii    7
1   a      b      Parabacteroides johnsonii      8
2   a      b      Parabacteroides merdae         9
3   a      b      Parabacteroides sp             10
4   c      d      Bacteroides coprocola          1
5   c      d      Bacteroides dorei              2
```

I would like to transform this table in latex format, but with the repeated values in Group 1 and Group 2 centred (see figure below for an example). In latex this is done with the package `\multirow`, and `df.to_latex` has a parameter called multirow to enable this ([to_latex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html))

[image]

However, a MultiIndex has to be created in order to use the `multirow` option in `to_latex`.
So I did this:

```
test.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(test[["Group 1","Group 2"]])
test = test.drop(["Group 1","Group 2"], axis=1)
test

                Species                 Adj. P-value
Group 1 Group 2     
a       b       Parabacteroides goldsteinii      7
        b       Parabacteroides johnsonii        8
        b       Parabacteroides merdae           9
        b       Parabacteroides sp               10
c       d       Bacteroides coprocola            1
        d       Bacteroides dorei                2
```

And finally I stored the table:

```
test.to_latex("la_tex_tab.txt",multirow=True, index=True,float_format="{:0.3f}".format).
```

However, this yields:

[image]

It works just for level 0 (Group 1) but not for level 1 (Group 2) of the MultiIndex. **Do you have any suggestions about how to avoid the repetitions of the values b and d in the MultiIndex?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of a hack if you want:

```
test['Group 2'] = test['Group 2'].mask(test['Group 2'].duplicated(),'')
test.set_index(["Group 1","Group 2"])
```

---

```
                        Species         Adj.  P-value
Group 1 Group 2                                       
a       b        Parabacteroides  goldsteinii        7
                 Parabacteroides    johnsonii        8
                 Parabacteroides       merdae        9
                 Parabacteroides           sp       10
c       d            Bacteroides    coprocola        1
                     Bacteroides        dorei        2
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do it for ***display only*** by use `assign` with blank column

```
test = test.assign(help='').set_index('help',append=True).drop(["Group 1","Group 2"], axis=1)
```